# How to check if file has correct prefix before removing it

Tags: linux, bash

I completed a script to add and remove 10 digit prefixes to all files in a given directory. If I apply the prefix then `ls /home/testing | cut -c1-10 | uniq` returns 1 single value - the prefix.

How can I put a validation in place in part of the script that removes the prefix, only to  remove prefix when filename has 10 digit prefix in it? Otherwise, if something somewhere goes wrong i can cut out first 10 characters from the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove only the `10 digit prefix` from filenames fairly easily using **character classes** and **string indexes**:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$1"/*; do

    fname=${i##*/}                               # separate filename from path
    [[ "${fname:0:10}" =~ [^0-9] ]] && continue  # skip if not 10 digit-prefix
    prefix=${fname:0:10}                         # get the prefix
    noprefix=${fname:10}                         # remove the prefix from beginning
    echo "$fname  =>  $noprefix"                 # do whatever with remaining fname
    # if [ "$prefix" = "$testvalue" ]; then      # validate correct prefix
    #     do something
    # fi

done
```

**input:**

```
$ ls -l dat/tmp
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Aug 25 17:06 a
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 02:31 b
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 02:30 c
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Jun 27 02:30 d
drwxr-xr-x 2 david david 4096 Nov  6 23:46 jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567890_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567891_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567892_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567893_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567894_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567895_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567896_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567897_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567898_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Nov 16 20:03 1234567899_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  139 Sep 23 15:57 file.back.1411505860
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  139 Sep 23 15:58 file.back.1411505898
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  189 Sep 27 11:37 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  115 Sep 27 11:36 nginx.conf.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  139 Aug 25 16:18 nm.txt
```

**output:**

```
$ bash tendigits.sh dat/tmp
1234567890_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567891_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567892_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567893_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567894_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567895_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567896_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567897_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567898_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
1234567899_file.txt  =>  _file.txt
```

When working in bash, it is generally more efficient and better suited to use the tools that bash provides rather than spawning subshells calling 3rd party tools like `grep` and `cut`. **Parameter expansion/substitution** and **substring extraction** can generally handle all your string parsing needs without spawning a single subshell. Every call to an external application like `grep` and `cut` spawns its own subshell and process. (just food for thought)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to check the length of the file to check if it is long enough - in the eaxmple below ${#f} returns the length of $f.

```
f=/home/testing
if [[ ${#f} -ge 10 ]];then
   echo $f | cut -c1-10
fi
```

Comment: I meant to check if prefix is 10 digit number for all files or not.  If ls /home/testing | cut -c1-10 | uniq returns multiple answers then something is not right.

Answer (score 0):

This will echo the names of files that start with at least 10 decimal digits.

```
for file in $(ls [0-9]*|grep "^[0-9]\{10\}"); do
    echo file=${file}
done
```

This will echo the count of files that have identical 10-digit prefix, the prefix, and each of the files that match that prefix

```
ls [0-9]* | grep "^[0-9]\{10\}" | cut -c1-10 | sort | uniq -c | while read count prefix; do
    echo count=$count prefix=$prefix $(ls ${prefix}*)
done
```